# How to automatically adjust R script based on # of variables (var1, var2, etc.)

Tags: r, string

Main dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 =c(1, 2, 1), var2 = c(2, 3, 3))
```

My mapping table:

```
mt <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 1), var2 = c(2, 3,3), color = c('red', 'blue', 'yellow'))
```

To merge df to mt, preserving all rows in df:

```
df <- merge(x = df, y=mt, by=c("var1", "var2"), all.x = TRUE)
```

QUESTION: How can I dynamically change the code so that if I have 4 number of vars (ie. var1, var2, var3, var4), the code will automatically get adjusted to the following?

`df <- merge(x = df, y=mt, by=c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), all.x = TRUE)`

Similarly, if we have 5 number of vars, it will be automatically get adjusted to:

`df <- merge(x = df, y=mt, by=c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5"), all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the datasets have the same column names that are used in `by`, then we don't need to specify the `by` as it automatically picks up the columns by matching the intersecting column names.

```
merge(df, mt, all.x = TRUE)
```

But, if there are other columns and want to only specify the "var" columns, then an option is either `startsWith`

```
merge(x = df, y=mt, by= names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "var")], all.x = TRUE)
```

or `grep`

```
merge(x = df, y=mt, by= grep("^var\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE), all.x = TRUE)
```